# How to get multiple variable from SQL command in set them to local variable using ExecuteScalar in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

Using this code I get my variable from an MS Access 2013 database and store it into a local variable:

```
public static int UpdateDBtCowsCalculatedVariable()
{
    string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);

    OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    Cmd.Connection = Connection;
    Cmd.CommandText = "Select BW from tCows";
    Connection.Open();
    int BW = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    Connection.Close();
        return BW;         
}
```

But what about multiple variables? How should I do that?

I mean something like this:

```
public static void UpdateDBtCowsCalculatedVariable()
{
    //int BW, DaysInMilk, AnimalType;
    string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);

    OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    Cmd.Connection = Connection;
    Cmd.CommandText = "Select BW, DaysInMilk, AnimalType from tCows";
    Connection.Open();
    int BW = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    // int DaysInMilk = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    // int AnimalType = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you only have 1 record in your database?

Comment: no, there is a lot of them, but for different purpose i need to select one of them or in this case 3 of them

Comment: @itsme86 Now i know what was your point, yes for now there is one record, and in the future when I want to add more record I will use where in my sql

Comment: Microsoft has an example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx#_OleDb

Comment: If you have this kind of doubts then I recommend to read some tutorial introduction to ADO.NET before committing yourself to something bigger than an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `ExecuteReader()`? Even if you, technically, have just one record:

```
public static void UpdateDBtCowsCalculatedVariable()
{
    string StrCon = ...

    int BW = -1; 
    int DaysInMilk = -1;
    int AnimalType = -1;

    using (OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon)) 
    {
        Connection.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            Cmd.Connection = Connection;
            Cmd.CommandText = 
              @"select BW, 
                       DaysInMilk, 
                       AnimalType 
                  from tCows";

            using (var reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read()) 
                {
                    BW =         Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                    DaysInMilk = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1));
                    AnimalType = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(2));   
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly because I was not familiar with ExecuteReader(), 
are you saying this is a better way for me to use?
tanks a lot

Comment: @SaraniO: it's easier to use (just execute the query and return what should be returned)

Comment: tanks again, it works perfectly, I have a question what the difference between 'using (OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand())' with what I used to write  OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon) ?
can I change your code to what I used to write?
tanks for your time

Comment: @SaraniO: wrapping `IDisposable` into `using` is a standard practice: in case any exception is thrown (for whatever reason) `using` syntax guarantees that resources (connection) allocated will be *released*; in your current implementation you'll have a *resource leak*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void UpdateDBtCowsCalculatedVariable() {
//int BW, DaysInMilk, AnimalType;

string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);

OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
Cmd.Connection = Connection;
Cmd.CommandText = "Select BW, DaysInMilk, AnimalType from tCows";
Connection.Open();
reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
  int BW = reader.GetValue(0);
  int DaysInMilk =  reader.GetValue(1);
  int AnimalType =  reader.GetValue(2);
}
reader.Close();
Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: you have no need to loop over the entire cusror: change `while (reader.Read())` into `if (reader.Read())`

Comment: `using` syntax is a better choice than `new ... Close()`: in case of any exception (whatever reason) `using` will free resources, while `new ... Close()` will *leak* resources.